# ¿Cómo hacer que un button realice una acción cuando se presione por primera vez y otra cuando se presione por segunda vez?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito saber si hay algún modo de hacer que al presionar un button se realice una acción y al presionarlo por segunda vez se realice otra acción. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Es muy importante que leas [ask], [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Una forma facil es que utilizes un flag o bandera, por ejemplo: una variable boleana te podria funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un simple contador puedes lograrlo, sería una variable global que aumente a medida que otro click se realice, puedes reiniciar el contador si deseas y con un condicional analizas el valor del contador, si es 1 haces algo y si es 2 haces otra cosa, mira este ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="saySomething()">Say something</button>
  <script>
    let clickCount = 0;
    
    function saySomething() {
      clickCount = ++clickCount % 2;
      
      if (clickCount == 1) sayHello();
      else                 sayBye();
    }

    function sayHello() {
      alert("Hello")
    }

    function sayBye() {
      alert("Bye");
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```